# Are we allowed to help devs by giving them money on paypal?

Tags: paypal

I'm not so rich, but I'm amazed by all of the excellent devs on Stack Overflow.

I wonder if some of you are giving them money via PayPal, when they help you so nicely?

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs on https://meta.stackoverflow.com , but it certainly seems that developers are allowed to let people donate to them via user profiles: [Linking to "PayPal Donate" in your About Me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265206/linking-to-paypal-donate-in-your-about-me)